# App Launching Time In Android mobile

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

This is balu, I have developed hybrid mobile application using IBM Worklight with jQuery mobile framework.

It is working fine but it is takes a long time (30 sec) during first time launch (8 sec black screen observed).

From 2nd time onwards it takes 17 sec, no black screen observed.

Please give me any idea how to make launching time shorter.

Thanks

Comment: We can't give tips if you don't provide information. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i am using worklight 6.0

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue.

I have upgraded to IBM Worklight 6.1.0.1 and this issue was resolved.

I think you can try the same.

Comment: Upgrading to Worklight 6.0.0.2 will suffice - this version contains a fix to make the launch time of a newly installed app (first time load) much faster. If you are an IBM customer or business partner you can get this from IBM Fix Central.